# Outlook add-in tools api

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I want to create an Outlook add-in tool that will allow me to point to an email and upload the entire message to a database I control. I am having difficulty finding good documentation on how to do this. Pointers and references appreciated.

Bob

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has an article called [Building a Custom Add-in for Outlook 2007 Using Windows Presentation Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410039.aspx).

There's a bunch of other stuff on MSDN, you can google it: http://www.google.se/search?hl=sv&rlz=1C1GGLS_svSE309SE303&q=outlook+add-in+site:msdn.microsoft.com&

(I tried to link that but the text-formatting thingy just don't like me or something)

Answer (score 2):

hmmm... you could do this yourself but you will eventually hit all kinds of issues that the OOM (outlook object model) can't handle.

your best bet is to investigate a pre-built solution. Essentially what you really need is an email archival solution. Most good ones (such as commvault) include both addins (for outlook) as well as sinks (for OWA).

You can then turn off PSTs altogether and allow users to manage all there non-mailbox email via the addin.

roll your own.. at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

There is quite alot of infomation on how to do this on the net. 
They range from building a macros in Outlook using VBA to building full blown VSTO addins.

I guess it depends on what you langs know what versions of outlook you are using how you want deploy etc.

www.outlookcode.com is a great place to start. 
and the api doc on msdn.

If you know VBA it is easy to knock something up first with a macro. you will then find out if you hit speed bumps and have to move to an addin